# End-extending cardinals

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

Let us say a cardinal $\kappa$ *end-extending* if there is a function $F : V_\kappa^{<\omega} \to V_\kappa$ such that:
(a) If $M \subseteq V_\kappa$ is closed under $F$, then $M \prec V_\kappa$.
(b) If $M$ is closed under $F$ and of size $<\kappa$, then there is $N \supseteq M$ closed under $F$ such that $N \cap \sup(M \cap \kappa) = M \cap \kappa$ and $N \cap \kappa \not= M \cap \kappa$.

It is a standard argument to show that measurable cardinals are end-extending, and this reflects below them.  It is fairly easy to see that end-extending cardinals must be regular and cannot be successor cardinals (except for the trivial case $\kappa = \omega_1$).

(1) Is being an end-extending limit cardinal equivalent to a well-known large cardinal notion?

(2) Must end-extending limit cardinals be strongly inaccessible?

Comment: Isn't this something like weakly compact?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was going to say weakly compact, but the fact that the carrier of the structure might be way bigger than $\kappa$ makes me sceptical.

Comment: @Miha: But does it also make you special?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Not without collapsing $\omega_1$ it doesn't.

Comment: Instead of a measurable, can you use a remarkable cardinal to do this (and reflect below)?

Comment: To be fair, when I said "something like", I mean one of those L-compatible cardinals.

Comment: An end-extending cardinal implies the existence of $0^\sharp$.  Just end-extend until you get an elementary submodel of $V_\kappa$ of size $\kappa$.  Then the transitive collapse gives you a nontrival $j : L_\kappa \to L_\kappa$.  Remarkable and weakly compact cardinals have strength below $0^\sharp$.

Comment: @MonroeEskew $<\kappa$-Erdos maybe? (Since you're sassuming $\kappa> \omega_1^V$)

Comment: @NotMike I’m not even sure Ramsey implies it. Do you see an argument for that?

Comment: I had a vauge notion about always being able to tack a new sequence of indescribables onto the end of a given $M\prec V_\kappa$ and take the hull of that. But thinking about it, I'm not entirely confident of how to code it all into one function or be sure it doesn't pick up new smaller ordinals..

Comment: Wait, isn't this just saying that $\kappa$ is the limit of weakly compact cardinals now? (Or a Mahlo limit of them, or something like that maybe...) Since if $\lambda<\kappa$ is WC and $M$ is a $\lambda$-models which is closed under $F$ then by weak compactness it has an end-extension.

Comment: @AsafKaragila no, by the $0^\sharp$ argument.

Comment: Ugh, you and your mathematical arguments...

Comment: @AsafKaragila: The point is that *every* submodel can be end-extended, including the non-transitive ones. So we can iterate forever.

Comment: The second theorem of this answer appears relevant  https://mathoverflow.net/a/309937/8843 (the portion of the question which defines the terms is just the first blurb and the "Definitions" bit)

Comment: (Whoops "indescribables" was suppose to be "indiscernibles".. )

Comment: @NotMike I think you can engineer a situation where adding indiscernibles introduces some new small ordinals. If you add some fixed accessible ordinal to each indiscernible, then the resulting set is still indiscernible.  But in the argument from a measurable, you add some new ordinal from a certain measure one set. So it’s about adding the “right” indiscernibles.

Comment: I think maybe one can show if $\kappa$ carries a $\omega_1$-saturated ideal $I$ on $\kappa$, then for any $M'\prec V_{\kappa+2}$ containing $I$ of size $<\kappa$, there exists $N\sqsupset M=_{def} M'\cap V_\kappa$

Comment: @JingZhang, I think you are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $\kappa$ carries an $\omega_1$-saturated $\kappa$-complete ideal $I$, given $M\prec (V_{\kappa+2},\in , <)$ ($<$ well orders $V_{\kappa+2}$) of size $<\kappa$ containing $I$, we show how to find an end-extension $N\prec V_{\kappa+2}$ of $M$ (i.e. $N\cap \sup(M\cap \kappa)=M\cap \kappa$).

Let $G\subset P(\kappa)/I$, and let $j: V\to N$ be the generic embedding in $V[G]$. Look at $M'=\{j(f)(\kappa): f\in M\}$. In $N$, $M'\prec j((V_{\kappa+2}, \in , <))$. Clearly $\kappa\in M'\cap j(\kappa)- j(M)$. Note $j(M)\cap j(\kappa)=j''M \cap j(\kappa)=j(M\cap \kappa)=j'' M\cap \kappa=M\cap \kappa$. If $\xi\in \kappa$ such that $\xi\in M'$, $\xi\in M$. The reason is that: fix $f$ such that $j(f)(\kappa)=\xi$. In $V$, $M$ contains a maximal antichain $\{A_i: i<\omega\}$ such that for each $i$, there exists $\delta_i<\kappa$, $A_i\Vdash j(f)(\kappa)=\delta_i$. Clearly $\{A_i: i<\omega\}, \{\delta_i: i<\omega\}\subset M$. Hence in $V[G]$, there exists $i<\omega$, $\xi=\delta_i \in M$. 
This shows $M'\cap \sup (j(M)\cap j(\kappa))=M'\cap \sup(M\cap \kappa)=M\cap \kappa=j(M)\cap j(\kappa)$.

By elementarity, there exists $N\prec V_{\kappa+2}$ containing $M$ such that $N\cap \sup (M\cap \kappa)=M\cap \kappa$ and $N\cap \kappa \neq M\cap \kappa$.

So $\kappa$ can be $2^\omega$.

Comment: This also works to show that for $\mu$-c.c. ideals, $\mu<\kappa$, almost all $M$ such that $M \cap \mu \in \mu$ can be end-extended.